# Fancybox - change parent content

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am using Fancybox as a popup when a product is added to a shopping cart.

I would like the popup to have two buttons - "Go to checkout" or "Continue shopping" where the continue shopping just closes the fancybox. That one is no problem.

What I cant seem to figure out is closing the fancybox and load the checkout page in the main/parent window. I would really appriciate some help on this one.

Answer (score 2):

You should be doing this in javascript for the click function on the Goto Checkout button.

```
function gotoCheckout()
{
    $.fancybox.close();
    window.location = "http://www.blah.com/cart/checkout"; //Change this to be the checkout URL
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an option(http://fancybox.net/api) 'onClosed' with which you should be able to call a function once the window  is closed. You function could just contain something like:

```
location.href = 'yoururl'
```